# pytest coverage - number of hits of a line

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py, pytest-cov

I have a file, `test_basic.py`:

```
class TestCalculator():
    def test_calculator(self):
        from basic import Basic
        basic_obj = Basic()
        sum_nums = basic_obj.add_num(1,2)
        diff_num = basic_obj.sub_num(3,5)
        prod_num = basic_obj.prod_num(5,5)
        quo_num = basic_obj.div_num(3,0)
```

I have another file, `basic.py`:

```
class Basic():
    def __init__(self):
        print ('Basic initialized')
    def add_num(self, num1, num2):
        counter = 0
        while (counter < 5):
            counter = counter + 1
        return (num1 + num2)
    def sub_num(self, num1, num2):
        return (num1 - num2)
    def prod_num(self, num1, num2):
        return (num1 * num2)
    def div_num(self, num1, num2):
        if not num2:
            return 0
        return num1/num2
    def lhospital(self, num1, num2):
        if num2 == 0:
            return 10000000
        else:
            return num1/num2
```

To get the coverage, I run this command:

`py.test --cov-report xml --cov=test/lib test/lib/test_basic.py`

In `coverage.xml`, I have the coverage report and an example for line 6,7 in `basic.py` is:

```
<line branch="true" condition-coverage="100% (2/2)" hits="1" number="6"/>
<line hits="1" number="7"/>
```

In `basic.py`, lines 6,7 are executed multiple times. Is there any way to change the `.coveragerc` file or maybe something else so that the number of hits for a line reflects multiple executions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Coverage.py doesn't support hit counts.  Maybe in the future it will.

Comment: Could you point me to the file(s) where I can implement this enhancement/feature? https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/src/9cf891202041c5cbafc19e8c2d5467db77100066/coverage/?at=default

Comment: Try using the "trace" module in the stdlib first.  It has this feature.

Comment: Did you end up implementing this? I would really like this feature as well.

Comment: Nope, not implemented yet.